# ordering two columns php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, tags, match

I have a query:

```
<?php

$results = $dbConn->select("SELECT entryA, entryB FROM table");

/**
Displays the rows on $results (entryA, entryB)
1      7
8      5
4      3
5      8
7      1
3      4
**/

$results = $dbConn->select("SELECT entryA, entryB FROM table ORDER BY ?");
/**
The correct output must be: (entryA, entryB)
1      7
7      1
8      5
5      8
4      3
**/


?>
```

How can i possible to order two columns that equal/match to each other ids in a different row?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. For example

```
SELECT entryA, entryB FROM table ORDER BY entryA*entryA+entryB*entryB
```

-in my samples I'm supposing you have both pair variants, i,e `{1,7}` and `{7,1}`, for example.

This will group same pairs independent of elements order, but you may wish to have additional order condition - then simply add it to `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: hi @Alma Do Mundo, the query that you gave has is sometimes correct sometimes not. the pair 7   1 jumps to the third row  1   7

Comment: @Shudmeyer and that depends of your data. My idea is to have some order-independent function (sum of squares is such function). In fact, this only indicates that order-independent pairs will follow one after another, but not entire rows order

Comment: sorry you just updated the query. it works great you save my day. thanks. :-*